# The configuration section 'connectionStrings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to move my webpage(c#) to ISS 7.5 server.

I have read that i need to put the  in WEBCONFIG to achieve the conection with sql server 2008.

I already did that.

Here is my WEBCONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionstrings>
   <!-- <remove name="LocalSqlServer" /> -->
    <add name="conexionsql" connectionstring="Data Source=FCH-DESARROLLO;Initial Catalog=DesaInterno;Integrated Security=True;User ID=usuario_de_conexion;Password=a"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionstrings> 


  <system.web>

    <!--<identity impersonate="true" /> -->

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <!--  <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/> -->
        <add assembly="*" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
   <!-- <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/> -->
  <!--  <authentication mode="Windows" /> -->
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>


 <!-- <system.webServer> -->
   <!-- <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument> -->

  <!--</system.webServer> -->
   <!-- <connectionStrings>
        <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
        <add connectionString="Server=10.10.201.79;Database=DesaInterno;Integrated Security=true" name="LocalSqlServer" />
    </connectionStrings> -->
</configuration>
```

When i try tu run my app in IIS comes an error.

> Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error The configuration section
>   'connectionStrings' cannot be read because it is missing a section
>   declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="#" connectionString="#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

---

replace your code with above configuration

as well the tag  should be in proper case exact as given

let me know if you still stuck its might be some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by copying machine.config file from the backup server.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string section has the following definition and **is case-sensitive**:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="conexionsql" connectionstring="Data Source=FCH-DESARROLLO;Initial Catalog=DesaInterno;Integrated Security=True;User ID=usuario_de_conexion;Password=a"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the keys are **case-sensitive** and you have it all lower-case `connectionstrings`, simply change to the correct case `connectionStrings` (note upper-case **S**).

Complete config (with redundant items removed) now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conexionsql" connectionstring="Data Source=FCH-DESARROLLO;Initial Catalog=DesaInterno;Integrated Security=True;User ID=usuario_de_conexion;Password=a"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings> 

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="*" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```