# Error 500.19 in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[Error 500.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpmzA.png)

I am getting above error when running program from VS2013.

here below is my web config file.

[web Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sADzt.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The configuration section 'connectionStrings' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797984/the-configuration-section-connectionstrings-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missi)

Comment: this solve my problem...thanx